# How can I keep a jQuery DOM element reference when splicing/sorting an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects.  One of the properties of these objects is a jQuery reference to a DOM element that may or may not actually be attached to the DOM at any given time;

For example:

```
Array = [{
      name : 'whatever 1',
      element : $('<div id="item_1" class="item"><img src="" /></div>')
},
{
     name : 'whatever 2',
     element : $('<div id="item_2" class="item"><img src="" /></div>')
}];
```

When this array is untouched I can detach and append these elements to the DOM without any troubles as well as use standard jQuery methods upon the elements.

For example:

```
Array[0].element.find('img');
```

...Will work fine.

However if I sort or splice this array, I lose the references.

I understand the reason why this is happening but what I would like to know is if there is anyway around this so that this element can continually be changed, attached, detached, modified while sorting or splicing the overall array itself?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Here is a code sample of my rearrange function:

```
    rearrangeItems : function(){
                        var self = this;

                        var offset = 0;


                        // get number of items that are less than insertindex
                        for(var i = 0; i < self.cache.selecteditems.length; i++) {
                                  if(self.cache.selecteditems[i] < self.cache.rearrangepos){
                                      offset++;
                                  }

                        }

//subtract the offset from the intended insertion index

            var rearrangeindex = self.cache.rearrangepos - offset;

            var removedItems = [];

//sort the selected element indexes into ascending order
            self.cache.selecteditems.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a < b) return -1;
                else if (b < a) return 1;
                return 0;
            });


//remove the selected array elemens from the overall array and push them into the temporary array    
            for(var i = 0; i < self.cache.selecteditems.length; i++) {
                var index = self.cache.selecteditems[i];
                removedItems.push(self.cache.items.splice(index - removedItems.length, 1)[0]);
            }

//Add the selected array elements back into the main array at the correct insertion point
            self.cache.items.splice.apply(self.cache.items, [rearrangeindex, 0].concat(removedItems));

    }
```

When calling this function all array elements are reordered exactly as intended.

Before reordering I can do the following:

```
self.cache.items[index].html.find('img');
```

Afterwards however, it will result in an empty object (the html property is the equivalent of the element property in my example above).

Comment: Keep the original array static and use a secondary array with references to that static index.

Comment: have you tried to use actual dom elements instead of jQuery elements? like `element:$('<div .../div>')[0]`.

Comment: No. The references will not change when sorting or splicing the array (only the array indizes will) - you must be doing something wrong. Please show us your sort/splice code. Also, you should not use `Array` as a variable name

Comment: @Bergi haven't Array as a variable name it was simply for example purposes.  Sorry for not being clear.  I will post a code sample now.

Comment: Hm, I can't see any obvious mistakes. Are you sure that every of the `self.cache.items` had a `html` property before rearranging them? Or are you accessing an other object now, as the `index` has changed?

Answer (score 0):

I would work with the ID, cause you have one. Don't know if this is the cleanest solution but it will work.

Calling your example like this:

```
$('#' + Array[0].element.attr('id')).find('img');
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this was down to my own stupidity.  In my code I was referencing the element incorrectly.

I was actually doing the following:

```
self.cache.items[index].html.find('#image_' + index);
```

After reordering the elements I was intentionally resetting indexes afterwards, therefore when calling this after a sort/reorder the element was incorrect.

by switching to a class selector everything was fixed.

```
self.cache.items[index].html.find('.image_item');
```

How embarrassing!  My apologies to all.